# apache and php Segmentation fault

Tags: arch-linux, php, apache-httpd, symfony

I have recently migrated to Archlinux. I installed Apache, php and mysql according to [the Arch Linux LAMP wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP).

Now I have setup a virtual host for my new [Symfony](http://symfony.com) project.

For every request I make, I get this error:

```
[notice] child pid 10859 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Do you get segfaults running the php cli directly from the command line? Try running `php -v` from a command line.

Comment: Not for `php -v`, but when I run `php -S 127.0.0.1:8070` and make a request, I get segfault.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. I added my response in an answer to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever PHP fails with anything other than parsing errors for me, I try running it from the console in CLI mode, example:

`php -v`

This will often lead me to the errors or problems that I cannot see when PHP runs within Apache.

This is merely a debugging step.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, guys.
I found the problem.
It was php's apc causing the segfault. I disabled it and now, it works fine. Special thanks to Tim for giving me a clue.

Comment: Installing APC from the repo's and not via PEAR fixes the problem, thank you!